# Difference in speed of addition positive and negative numbers

Tags: c#, clr

I've go a very simple code for addition of two integer number

```
    public class SimpleCalculator
{
    public int Add(int a,int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    public int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

And a small UnitTest based on NUnit for it

```
    [TestFixture]
    [Category("Math")]
    public class SimpleCalculatorTests
    {
        [TestCase(-5,10,5)]
        [TestCase(0, 0, 0)]
        [TestCase(2, 3, 5)]
        [TestCase(7, 10, 17)]
        [TestCase(30, 40, 70)]
        [Category("Addition")]
        public void ShouldAddTwoNumbers(int firstNum, int secondNum, int expectedNum)
        {
            //System Under Test - sut
            var sut = new SimpleCalculator();

            var result = sut.Add(firstNum, secondNum);

            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expectedNum));

        }
    }
```

Results are the following

- ShouldAddTwoNumbers(0,0,0) - Duration: less then 1ms
- ShouldAddTwoNumbers(2,3,5) - Duration: less then 1ms
- ShouldAddTwoNumbers(30,40,70) - Duration: less then 1ms
- ShouldAddTwoNumbers(-5,10,5) - Duration: less then 15ms
- ShouldAddTwoNumbers(7,10,17) - Duration: less then 1ms

Why such a big duration for test with negative number involved in comparison with other tests?

Comment: I strongly suspect you're just seeing a quirk of the way the timing is performed. Try calling the method a million times in a loop so you're measuring a more reasonable chunk of time.

Comment: Post all your code, including how you are performing the timings. Adding two numbers will take microseconds.

Comment: I've checked as you had recommended. For 1 million every test except negative one gave 7ms. Negative 20ms. For 100 million all test almost the same plus/minus 10-25ms

Comment: Dear  Matthew Watson. I am just using VS2015 test explorer and getting duration information from it.No additional timing in code

Comment: There's no way that an add operation will take 10-25ms. For starters, the add time will be dwarfed by the amount of time it takes to call the methods you wrote to add two numbers together AND you're also timing how long it takes to call `Assert.That()`. For seconds, you're running in debug mode using test explorer. Your timings are meaningless because of that.

Comment: Also note that the "slow" test is the first one performed. Try reordering the list of test cases and see how it alters the results (put the negative numbers later in the list)>

Comment: i just noticed - you're also including the time it takes to create an instance of `SimpleCalculator`! So what you're doing is lumping together a bunch of calls that will take literally millions of times longer than an add operation, timing them, and then wondering what this says about how long the add operation took...

Comment: Matthew! Thanks for detailed answer! It seems that you are right.